# Mysql Unique constraints across 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I just started using sqlalchemy so my question below might not make sense but bear with me. I have two columns in my table colA and colB. I want elements of colA and colB to be unique across both the columns. 
For example if,

```
     ColA  ColB
row1 1     2 
row2 3     2 X(2 is already present in row1 ColB, therefore is a duplicate)
row3 4     1 X(1 is already present in row1 ColA, therefore is a duplicate)
```

then row2 and row3 in the example above must not be allowed. How do I do this in sqlalchemy? I have already researched about this and looked at other similar question but haven't found a suitable answer yet.

Comment: You may have to use a calculated column that combines the two columns in sorted order, and then place a unique key on that column.

Comment: It's clear why the duplicate `1, 2` item is not allowed. But it's not clear from your question why the item `3, 1 X`  is considered a duplicate. Can you please [edit] your question to be specific about that?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Use your DBMS to create a two-column unique index.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX myindex (colA, colB);
```

If I understand your question correctly, this will constrain your table the way you want.